# Docker check history of bash

Tags: docker

After someone executed:

```
docker exec -it ImageName /bin/bash
exit
```

Can i check the history of that bash?

I don't think that `docker image inspect` is right command here or `docker history`

Answer (score 1):

You need to enter the stopped container (if still present) to get the history of bash inside it:

```
# The only way is to first create an image from it
docker commit $STOPPED_CONTAINER user/test_image

# Then run a container based on the image to launch the `history` command inside it
docker run --rm -ti user/test_image history
```

[Source](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/18078#issuecomment-158525729)

Answer (score 1):

**Q:** Is there any way I can check the history of the `bash` shell for a docker container?

**A:** Yes you can. When a user exits the shell session, its history is written to a file called `.bash_history` and it is located in the user's home directory, in this case `/root/.bash_history`.

One of the easiest way to access the content of it would be to mount the file as a volume to another file on your host.

**Example:**

```
touch container_bash_history

docker run -v $(pwd)/container_bash_history:/root/.bash_history IMAGE_NAME
```

You may want to take note of the **absolute** file path that was specified in the `-v` option above. It is important because it indicates to `docker` that the mount will be done as a single file mount, not the usual directory mount.